# How to display a PDF bytearray in browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have been trying the below client side code to render the PDF byte array returned from server side. It shows the correct number of thumbnails/pages in browser but the content is not displaying. Both the thumbnails and the pages are completely black.
Is there anything I am missing here? Also, I read that createObjectURL is deprecated. Is there any better way to achieve this?

Thank you!

Server side code:

```
byte[] bytes = service.GetDocument(ID);

result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("inline");
```

Client side code:

```
@model DocumentWeb.ViewModels.Document

<html>
    <body>

        <object data="" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
        </object>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function (e) {

                $("object").attr("width", screen.availWidth);

                $("object").attr("height", screen.availHeight);

                var url = "@Url.Content("~/pdf/document")";
            
                    var data = {
                        ID: "@Model.DocID",
                    };

                    var result = $.post({
                        url: url,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: data
                    });

                    result.done(function (bytearray) {

                        var blob = new Blob([bytearray], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                        var link= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                        $("object").attr("data", link);
                    
                    });

                    result.fail(function (xhr) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    });
                
            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could always base64 encode your byte array. HTML `<object>` tags support base64 encoded images. Something like `<object src="data:application/pdf;base64, ABC123... />` where `ABC123...` is your base64 encoded PDF binary.

Comment: Thank you. It works now.

Comment: Since my suggestion appears to have worked for you I have provided it as an answer to this question, so that it may help others with similar issues in the future. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could always base64 encode your byte array. HTML `<object>` tags support base64 encoded images. Something like `<object src="data:application/pdf;base64, ABC123... />` where `ABC123...` is your base64 encoded PDF binary.